# Unity - Weapon Switching by MouseWheel With Locked Positions (Arena Shooter Style)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

I have been struggling to figure out how to implement an arena style shooter weapon switching using the mouse wheel.

Thus far I have 3 lists created; one list is all of the available Guns (of class Gun [0 = pistol, 1 = repeater, 2 = sniper, 3 = rocket launcher]), the next list is a boolean list with fixed positions to tell you whether the player has unlocked that gun (again 0,1,2,3 are fixed).  I have a third list which starts out as the guns you own and has a new one added to it when you touch the pick up.

I have easily gotten alpha key weapon switching, and a quick weapon switch (toggle between previous weapon and current), but the mouse scroll is driving me bonkers.

I am sure I am over thinking this but I'm just not sure what to do in the following scenarios:
The player only has the sniper and the pistol, thus meaning I can't just do a simple -1 or that would move to the index for the repeater which the player doesn't have when scrolling down.

I can get it working where it will swap with the next weapon (ie: from 0 to 3) but if I then pick up the repeater or the sniper, it will keep switching only through the pistol and rocket launcher.

I really don't know what I'm doing here I guess... I keep trying different for loops to iterate through the lists.  What I'd really like to know is if there is a simple way to step through the list and just get the next index or if we reach the end of the list, go to the first index.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Jacob

EDIT: (As requested here are the relevant code snippets)

Here are the variables in my playercontroller:

```
//GUNS GUNS GUNS

public Gun activeGun;
public List<Gun> allGuns = new List<Gun>();
public List<bool> unlockedGuns = new List<bool>();
public List<Gun> gunsAvailable = new List<Gun>();
public int currentGun = 0;
private int previousGun;
```

In my Update() function:

```
    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel") != 0f)
    {
        SwitchGunByMouse(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"));

    }
```

Here is the SwitchGun() method which works fine with the alpha keys or quick switch key.

```
public void SwitchGun(int gunNumber)
{
    if (cannotChangeWeapon) return;
    
    //if (currentGun == gunNumber) return;

    if (gunNumber < 0)
    {
        gunNumber = allGuns.Count - 1;
    }

    if (gunNumber > allGuns.Count - 1)
    {
        gunNumber = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < unlockedGuns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(i == gunNumber && unlockedGuns[i])
        {
            activeGun.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            activeGun = allGuns[gunNumber];
            activeGun.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            previousGun = currentGun;
            currentGun = gunNumber;
            UIController.instance.ammoText.text = "AMMO: " + activeGun.ammo;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method being called which does not work, this is the source where I last tried to fiddle with it.

```
public void SwitchGunByMouse(float direction)
{

    if (direction == 0f) return;

    int nextGun = -1;

    if (gunsAvailable.Count -1 > 0)
    {
        if (direction > 0f)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < gunsAvailable.Count -1; i++)
            {
                if (currentGun == gunsAvailable[i].idNumber) continue;
                if (currentGun < gunsAvailable[i].idNumber)
                    nextGun = gunsAvailable[i].idNumber;
            }

            if (nextGun == -1)
                nextGun = 0;
        }

        if (direction < 0f)
        {
            //int currentPos = gunsAvailable.idNumber;

            nextGun = gunsAvailable[currentGun].idNumber -1;
            
            List<Gun> g = gunsAvailable;
            
            g.Reverse();

            for(int i = 0; i < g.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (currentGun == g[i].idNumber) continue;
                if (currentGun < g[i].idNumber)
                    nextGun = g[i].idNumber;
            }
            
            //Okay so if we still haven't found a gun it means the other gun has a high id than our current gun
            //so now we need to figure out how to cycle again

            if(nextGun == -1)
            {
                nextGun = 0;
            }

        }

        Debug.Log("NextGun: " + nextGun);

        if (nextGun > -1)
            SwitchGun(nextGun);
        else 
            Debug.Log("Something bad happened with SwitchGunByMouse()");

    }
    
}
```

And lastly:

```
public bool WeaponPickup(string gunToAdd, Gun myGun)
{
    switch(gunToAdd)
    {
        case "Repeater":
            if(unlockedGuns[1] == true)
                return false;
            else
            {
                unlockedGuns[1] = true;
                myGun.isCollected = true;
                gunsAvailable.Add(allGuns[1]);
                return true;
            }
        case "Sniper":
            if (unlockedGuns[2] == true)
                return false;
            else
            {
                unlockedGuns[2] = true;
                myGun.isCollected = true;
                gunsAvailable.Add(allGuns[2]);
                return true;
            }
        case "Rocket Launcher":
            if (unlockedGuns[3] == true)
                return false;
            else
            {
                unlockedGuns[3] = true;
                myGun.isCollected = true;
                gunsAvailable.Add(allGuns[3]);

                return true;
            }
        default:
            Debug.Log("Weapon Pickup ran into a problem with gunToAdd not matching a predefined string.");
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be very easy for us to understand if we can see the code rather than reading it.

Comment: Okay let me edit.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between the lists `gunsAvailable` and `unlockedGuns`. Correct me if I'm wrong but whenever an element in `unlockedGuns` is `true` then it is also present in `gunsAvailable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    public void SwitchGunByMouse(float direction)
    {
        if (gunsAvailable.Count <= 1 || cannotChangeWeapon)
        {
            return;
        }

        int gunSwitchDirection = Mathf.Sign(direction);
        int gunCandidate = currentGun;
        bool isCorrect = false;

        do
        {
            gunCandidate += gunSwitchDirection;

            if (gunCandidate < 0)
            {
                gunCandidate = allGuns.Count -1;
            }
            else
            {
                gunCandidate %= allGuns.Count;
            }

            isCorrect = gunCandidate != currentGun && unlockedGuns[gunCandidate];
        }
        while (gunCandidate==currentGun || !unlockedGuns[gunCandidate]);

        SwitchGun(gunCandidate);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You can also clean up the `SwitchGun` method a bit:

```
    public void SwitchGun(int gunNumber)
    {
        if (cannotChangeWeapon) return;

        //if (currentGun == gunNumber) return;

        if (gunNumber < 0)
        {
            gunNumber = allGuns.Count - 1;
        }
        else if (gunNumber > allGuns.Count - 1)
        {
            gunNumber = 0;
        }

        if (unlockedGuns[gunNumber])
        {
            activeGun.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            activeGun = allGuns[gunNumber];
            activeGun.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            previousGun = currentGun;
            currentGun = gunNumber;
            UIController.instance.ammoText.text = "AMMO: " + activeGun.ammo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay this is functionally working except scrolling down is frequently returning an Argument out of range exception.  Err it happens when we're on currentGun = 0 and scrolling down (which should cycle back to the highest position)

Comment: You're right, I've com,pletely overlooked this scenario. I've updated my answer with a fix to this isuue

Comment: Just got back from an emergency trip to fix a sensor.  Going to add in your code and see what happens.

Comment: This new code worked perfectly.  Holy cow man this problem was driving me up a wall.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you try to search your array up or down and stop the search, when we find a element which is true.

```
public void SwitchGunByMouse(float direction)
{
    if (gunsAvailable.Count > 1)
    {
        int up = 1 ? direction > 0f: -1;
        for(int i = currentGun + direction; i == currentGun; i += direction)
        {
             // first we make sure our index is not going to be under 0 which does not exist in a array element
             if(i < 0)
             { 
                 i = unlockedGuns.Count-1;
             }
             // next we make sure our index doesn't crush the upper bounds of our array
             if(i > unlockedGuns.Count - 1)
             {
                 i = 0;
             }
             // if the index is in the bounds of our array we check if the boolean is true 
             // if yes, the loop will finish and we have our new weapon
             if(unlockGuns[i])
             {
                currentGun = i;
                return;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know how to do that when I get to my coding computer I'll give this a shot.  Thank you so much for your help.  Like you don't know how much it means to get help I've been banging my head on this for 2 days straight and just lacked the skill to solve it.  Can you explain what the ? operator is doing? It seems like it's saying, "UNLESS" then giving a condition to change it?

Comment: Okay so it seems you cannot use a while(true) in Unity or it causes the engine to hard lock

Comment: You can, you just need a proper stop condition, the solution provided by Leo doesn't always stop

Comment: Oh, yes thats correct. I assumed there is always at least one element true in the array.